# How to force cast and convert datatype in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

Im a swift developer with no knowledge in objective c.
Can any one help me with converting the below code in Objective C

```
let newVersion = Int((userInfo.value(forKey: 
"gcm.notification.version") as string).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))
let currentVersion = Int((userDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentAppVersion") as string).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))



if(newVersion > currentVersion) {
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
    NSString *newVersion = [(NSString *)[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"gcm.notification.version"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *oldVersion = [(NSString *)[standardDefaults valueForKey:@"currentAppVersion"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];

    if ([newVersion integerValue] > [oldVersion integerValue]){
        //code here
    }
```

Comment: @Ravi This will not work for cases with more digits. For instance check 2.1.1 > 1.1.11. In your case you would have 211 > 1111 which would report that version 1.1.11 is greater than 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo; // Assuming this is a dictionary
NSString *newVersionString = userInfo[@"gcm.notification.version"];
newVersionString = [newVersionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
NSInteger newVersion = [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:newVersionString] integerValue];

NSString *currentVersionString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentAppVersion"];
currentVersionString = [currentVersionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
NSInteger currentVersion = [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:currentVersionString] integerValue];

if(newVersion > currentVersion) {
    //code here
}
```

But this is not how you compare versions. The problem now is that for instance `1.11.1` is equal to `11.1.1`. Or in other words reposition dots anyway you can but if number of digits and their order stay the same then you will detect it as a same version. You should do this per component (both in Swift or Objective-C):

```
NSDictionary *userInfo;
NSArray<NSString *> *newComponents = [userInfo[@"gcm.notification.version"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSString *currentVersionString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentAppVersion"];
NSArray<NSString *> *currentComponents = [currentVersionString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

BOOL newVersionIsGreater = NO;
if(newComponents.count != currentComponents.count) newVersionIsGreater = newComponents.count > currentComponents.count;
else {
    for(int i=0; i<newComponents.count; i++) {
        NSInteger newInteger = [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:newComponents[i]] integerValue];
        NSInteger currentInteger = [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:currentComponents[i]] integerValue];
        if(newInteger != currentInteger) {
            newVersionIsGreater = newInteger > currentInteger;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(newVersionIsGreater) {
    //code here
}
```

This now checks if we have same number of components in both cases and then iterates through them. The first component that differs will report a change.

Comment: This Helped me in exact way i want. Thank you @Matic